# Store xpathResult.snapshotItem in a local variable?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I am trying to create a cross-browser interface for xml, specifically using an XPath expression to select nodes.

IE was easy:

```
this.documentElement.selectNodes(xPathStr);
```

returns an object that gives array-like access (`results[i]` or `results(i)`).

However, Firefox/chrome is not as easy.

```
this.xpathEvaluator.evaluate(xPathStr, this.documentElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

returns an XPathResult that can either be iterated through or accessed almost array-like using `results.snapshotItem(i)`.

I tried doing

```
var items = results.snapshotItem;
```

but that gave me an error when I tried to use it ("Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object").

Any ideas on how I can cache this as an array-like variable, or am I stuck creating the array manually and then returning that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to switch restults to nodes:

```
    var item = nodes.snapshotItem[i];
```

I'm working on a similar project (with different problems), but that's worked for me. However, I'm guessing you could do this:

```
    var items = nodes.snapshotItem;
```

and later call items[i]. I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Best to know you're proving a useful answer, but thanks for your involvement